# onActivityCreated method is called in one fragment but not other

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I am working on a tablet application.I have created to fragment one for List Of Item and other for detail of item. There are `onActivityCreated` method in both fragment class.both fragment are used in one actvity class. I have a problem that `onActivityCreated` method is called for one activity but not other. I want to ask that how `onActivityCreated` work.I want to call a method for second fragment actvity `onActvityCreated` method.
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: check this post, there is problem description and common workaround solution: http://shomeser.blogspot.com/2014/01/nested-fragments-for-result.html

Answer (score 2):

`onActivityCreated()` is called after the Fragment is created, just like `onCreate()` is called when an Activity is created. To know about the frament lifecylce, click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

Answer (score 1):

I use an observer pattern and let my fragments register to get activity results.

```
public abstract class MyActivity {

    protected static Set<ActivityListener> mListenerSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<ActivityListener>(4,0.75f));

    public interface ActivityListener {
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Register for getting {@link MyActivity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} calls 
     *
     * @param listener Callback according to interface {@link ActivityListener}
     */
    public void registerListener(ActivityListener listener) {
        MyLog.v(LOG_TAG, "registerListener()");
        mListenerSet.add(listener);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Unregister to stop receiving {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} calls 
     *
     * @param listener Callback according to interface {@link ActivityListener}
     */
    public void unregisterListener(ActivityListener listener) {
        MyLog.v(LOG_TAG, "unRegisterListener()");
        mListenerSet.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        for (ActivityListener listener : mListenerSet) {
            listener.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

and then just let your fragment implement ActivityListener

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements ActivityListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MyActivity) getActivity()).registerListener(this);
        [...]
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        ((MyActivity) getActivity()).unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```